# Validate unique field in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app, I've got two models - `User` and `Account`.

A `User` can have many `Accounts`.

An `Account` includes a `name` field as shown in the schema below.

How can I validate that the `name` field is unique for an `Account` but not necessarily unique in the database? For example, `User1` could have an `Account` with the name `Cash` and `User2` could have a different `Account` but with the same name `Cash`.

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :email, presence: true,
                    length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_secure_password

  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end
end
```

account.rb:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :balances

  before_save { self.active = true }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 250 },
                  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

schema.rb:

```
  ....
  create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.boolean  "credit"
    t.boolean  "active",     default: true, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "balances", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.decimal  "balance"
    t.date     "date"
    t.integer  "account_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.boolean  "admin"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `scope`:

in your `account.rb`

```
validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id}
```

four you actual validates:

```
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 250 },
                  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false, scope: :use_id }
```

[active record validates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)